# Include relative file when run from cron

Tags: php, cron, command-line-interface

Consider a simple PHP script:

```
$ pwd
/var/www/site/public_html

$ cat a.php
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
echo "a: ".getcwd();
require_once('b.php');
?>

$ cat b.php
<?php
echo "b: ".getcwd();
?>

$ ./a.php > output
$ cat output
a: /var/www/site/public_html
b: /var/www/site/public_html
```

I then set up a simple cron job:

```
* * * * * /var/www/site/public_html/a.php > /var/www/site/public_html/output
```

However, this is the output after cron has run:

```
$ cat output
a: /home/user
```

The path has changed and the require function can no longer find the script to include. Frustratingly, I have another server on which the cron job does keep it's path. I have gone up and done the config options but cannot figure out how to configure PHP to keep the original path even when run as a cron job. How is this done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
$fileRoot = dirname(__FILE__);
require_once($fileRoot.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'b.php'); 
/* considering b.php is in same directory */
```

Comment: This really is the best, most portable answer.

Answer (score 3):

In your cron command, you can set the script to run within a specified working directory:

```
cd /var/www/site/public_html && ./a.php > output
```

Comment: Thank you MrCode. I moved the accepted answer to Waqar's answer as his answer really does address the root of the problem.